# Error processing request:Failed to link com/eaio/uuid/UUID

Tags: jboss

I am using jboss eap 7 and the uuid library eaio and run my application displays the following message:

Stack Trace:

**org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/eaio/uuid/UUID (Module "deployment.***-dtoEAR.ear.****-dto.war:main" from Service Module Loader): org/omg/CORBA/portable/IDLEntity**

With jboss eap 6 that does not happen.

Comment: Jason share whole stack trace

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with inbuilt modules provided by JBoss EAP 7. JBoss 6 provides */org/jacorb/main/jacorb-2.3.2-redhat-2.jar* module which has *org/omg/CORBA/portable/IDLEntity* class file.

But in JBoss EAP 7, IDLEntity is provided by module */javax/orb/api/main/openjdk-orb-8.1.2.Final-redhat-00001.jar*. Because of which your application is able to run on JBoss 6 but not on JBoss 7.

Try adding */org/jacorb/main/jacorb-2.3.2-redhat-2.jar* module to your JBoss EAP 7 modules. It should resolve your issue.